# Create a request with zeep that includes AnyObject types

Tags: python, soap, request, zeep

This is basically the same question as here:

[creating any object with python zeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019471/creating-any-object-with-python-zeep)

I am working on a Python script that includes SOAP API calls.  Mostly these are working but I am having a problem with one.  I have SOAPUI example working, it looks like this:

### soap ui that works

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="Urn:ApiService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:getAllOperationalDevices soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="api:ResourceIdentityInfo" xmlns:api="http://api.common.configmgr.powerup.com">
          <resourceKey xsi:type="soapenc:string">0a053ebeddf9e53f53e125d364010000</resourceKey>
         <resourceName xsi:type="soapenc:string">Customer1</resourceName>
         <resourceType xsi:type="soapenc:string">NETWORK</resourceType>
         </in0>
          <in1 xsi:type="fil:FilterInfo" xmlns:fil="http://filter.api.common.configmgr.powerup.com">
               <filterComponents>
                    <FilterExpressionInfo xsi:type="ns:FilterExpressionInfo" xmlns:ns="http://filter.api.common.configmgr.powerup.com">
                        <attributeName>managementIpAddress</attributeName>
                        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">10.10.10.10</value> 
                        <operator>==</operator>
                    </FilterExpressionInfo>
                </filterComponents>
          </in1>
      </urn:getAllOperationalDevices>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I see in the WSDL that the filter value is 
    AnyType:

And I see in the zeep documentation that there is special handling for AnyType, with the example I copied in my code below:

### zeep documentation example of AnyType

```
client = Client('http://my-entrprisy-endpoint.com')
value = xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(), 'foobar')
client.service.submit_something(user_id=1, my_string=value)
```

My attempt to create this request in zeep looks like:

### my python that returns error

```
print("API: getAllOperationalDevices")
in0 = {'resourceKey':nkey,'resourceName':nname,'resourceType':ntype}
value = xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(),dmgmtip)
filter = {'attributeName':'managementIpAddress','value':value,'operator':'=='}
feInfo = {'FilterExpressionInfo' : [filter]}
filComp = {'filterComponents' : feInfo}
result = client.service.getAllOperationalDevices(in0,filComp)
```

I think this should be pretty close but I get the error below:

### my python error

```
File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/any.py", line 181, in validate
raise exceptions.ValidationError("Missing element for Any")
```

My attempts to use zeep's client.service.get_element and client.service.get_type are failing because the namespace is not recognized, seems like it should be 'urn:getAllOperationalDevices' but evidently it is not.

If anyone can give me a nudge in the right direction I'd appreciate it!